# What can I do for hard disk error?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, scan-disk, hd-tune

It's a follow-up question for this question.
[Dropped external HDD](https://superuser.com/questions/1019310/dropped-external-hdd)

Using HD Tune, I learned that my external HDD has some errors on it.
Then what can/should I do?

Is there any way that I can 'flag' the damaged part so that this part is not used any more and move my data to undamaged part?

Comment: You replace the drive.  [You can indeed mark a sector bad and the HDD will stop using it, a HDD only has a certain amount of spare sectors, once the number of bad sectors are greater then the amount of spare sectors your options are limited.](http://superuser.com/questions/694422/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-mark-bad-sectors-without-data-recovery). This does not work if the HDD is physically damaged.  If you care about the data stored on this disk you should replace it, not try to put a band-aid on it, and forget about it.

Comment: **This is only a band-aid till you can get a new drive** If you have Windows OS, you can **chkdsk /R x:** replacing X: with your drive letter.  This only hides the problem.  Like using duct tape on a cracked windshield, eventually the crack will cause the whole window to break.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixing bad sectors](http://superuser.com/questions/332618/fixing-bad-sectors)